# How to remove scrollbar from iframe and still scroll inside it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

`<div class="wikipedia"><iframe height="500" src="https://en.wikipedia.org" class="frame" name="frame" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" allowtransparency="true"></iframe></div>`

This is my code!

**How can I still scroll inside this iframe using mouse scroll?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide scroll bar, but while still being able to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll)

Comment: Note that the `scrolling` attribute does nothing in modern browsers, and is considered [obsolete in HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-scrolling).